# Access only current portion of email

Tags: php, email

I am using the imap_xxxx functions to read the emails body. My problem is to find out only the current portion of the email body not the complete email. When user reply for an email it not only contains the his response but the complete mail chain. I know that facebook does it (or may be many other sites also) but how...

Comment: You have to be able to determine where the quoted previous messages begin; ie, split on `/-+\s*Original Message\s*-+/` for Outlook plaintext messages. It can get messy, though. @MikeB - Do you know of a means to "parse" an email and auto-split the various quoted previous messages below the original? I'd like to have a better solution than the manual methods I've used.

Comment: But anyone has any code pointer which can help me to parse the email...

Comment: Or get the email body, and just counts a certain number of characters. That should be a fairly trivial thing.